# how can i exclude 2 url from rewriting by apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, ckeditor4.x

i wrote a framework using clean url with this structure /fa/site/controller/method/id.the problem is ckfinder integrated with ckeditor in upload and browse pictures use another type of url. i want to exclude these addresses fron rewiting may help to work.
my htaccess codes is

```
    AddType text/css .css
<Files "*.js">
    ForceType text/javascript
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/public/admin/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/admin/plugins/ckfinder/1$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

i am using wamp v. 2.4.17
comments are my tries to help the story but not helped.
any help is appreciated